# Lotus Notes - Column view as Totals: Total showing not 0.00 even if there aren't no docs saved

Tags: view, lotus-notes

I have a view which contains a column ( as Total ) . Even, there aren't any docs created, the column shows:

165.65 ( as total ) and not 0.00 ( as it should be )

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the view show documents in a response hierarchy? Probably there is an "orphaned" response (Replication conflict or other reason) that is not shown in the view as the parent document is missing, but still is counted in the total- column. Try disable response- hierarchy in the View- Properties and check if there is such a document.

An additional reason for the total not being 0 could also be a document that is protected by a readers- field. Server will add this document to the totals (as View- Index is created by the server) whereas the Designer / User does not see the document. 
If you know, what is in the Readers- Field (Role, GroupName, etc.) then make yourself member of that field (by assigning the Role to yourself or add yourself to the group). 
If you don't know, what's in there (or something went wrong filling the readers field, e.g. forgot to tick the "multi value"- property), then you need somebody with "Full Access Administration"- right to the server. This Admin- function ovverrides all Reader- fields and makes the document visible to you.

Comment: Even I don't use response doc, the property 'Show response documents in a hierarchy' was checked. I disable it, but still, same result. Interesting is that, if the first column ( which has a field value as the default column value ) is CATEGORIZED, the categorized twisty and the field value appears, but still I can not selected the doc to delete !!! :(

Comment: Then there is a document that is protected with a reader- field. Try using the Full Access Administrator to make the document visible and delete it...